# I want to save the image to sub direcory that is on runtime in cakephp image uploadify

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I try this..but not create the subfolder...i don't understant where is the problem..

```
$user_id = $this->User->id;
if(!empty($prof_image['name'])){
$image_name = str_replace($prof_image['name'], 'profile', $prof_image['name']);
$dest = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'img' . DS . 'filocity_img' . DS . 'user_'. $user_id . DS . $image_name . '.jpg';
if(move_uploaded_file($prof_image['tmp_name'], $dest)){
    echo json_encode('Information successfully updated');
}
}
```

can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Variables in Cake apps should be camelCased and not underscored like $prof_image, also abbreviations in var names suck. Also there is a security flaw, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php. And Fuhrmann is right: Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using CakePHP file and folder utility.

At first add:

```
<?php 
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
```

Then try this :

```
$user_id = $this->User->id;
if(!empty($prof_image['name'])){
   $image_name = str_replace($prof_image['name'], 'profile', $prof_image['name']);
   $dest = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'img' . DS . 'filocity_img' . DS . 'user_'. $user_id;
 $dir = new Folder($dest, true, 0777);
 $file = new File($dir. DS . $image_name . '.jpg');
 if($file){
    echo json_encode('Information successfully updated');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but not create the subfolder

If you want to save the image in a sub directory that does not exist, you must create it before calling `move_uploaded_file()`

[The destination directory must exist; move_uploaded_file() will not automatically create it for you](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#105026)

If this is not the problem, then you need to provide more details in your question.